# Powershell - changing registry entry for Proxyserver

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I have a script that changes the internet proxy server. It is under `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer`.  The problem is, I seem to have to wait a while for the change to be reflected (so I can use the browser) or go into the Internet Options in Windows and click on Connections and open the Lan Settings and click Ok.

Is there something else I can do in my script to make the proxy reflected immediately in my browser?  Closing and opening the browser doesn't seem to make it happen either.

I mostly use Chrome, but have the same issue with IE.

Comment: Does it still happen if you restart the browser?

Comment: Yes. That doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: How long is "a while" ? Can you reproduce this on multiple profiles ? On multiple computers ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not experience any delay on Win8.1 with IE and Firefox, did you try it this way ?

Close the browsers *before* making the change.

```
$regPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"

#Enable proxy
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name "ProxyEnable" -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name "ProxyServer" -Value "proxy.domain:1080"

#Disable proxy
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name "ProxyEnable" -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name "ProxyServer" -Value ""
```

Comment: Yes. That is what I am doing.  It does work instantly if I close the browser first.  I was hoping to continue working on whatever I was working on in the browser, but I guess that isn't going to happen.

Comment: I guess the browser loads its settings at startup.

Comment: I don't find that closing the browser before applying the key always works.  Going into the LAN Connections always seems to work.